# Persistent "Sticky" Headers within a div with height and overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been researching this a bit and can't seem to find the right answer.

I have this codepen example that I put together using an example from CSS-Tricks.

[Persistent headers "Sticky headers"](http://codepen.io/g3sal/pen/wMorJX)

It works fine as is, but I want to set the properties of the container div `#page-wrap` from:

```
#page-wrap { 
   width: 500px; 
   margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

to

```
#page-wrap { 
   width: 500px; 
   height: 300px;
   background: red;
   overflow-y: auto;
   margin: 0 auto; 
 }
```

The result is that the functionality "breaks". I understand that the javascript sets the browser window as the container, but I'd like to "pin" or "bind" the sticky headers to the top of `#page-wrap` container instead the browser window .

Here is the JS:

```
    function UpdateTableHeaders() {

    $(".persist-area").each(function() {

    var el = $(this),
      offset = el.offset(),
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

    if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
      floatingHeader.css({
        "visibility": "visible"
      });
    } else {
      floatingHeader.css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
      });
    };
  });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

  var clonedHeaderRow;

  $(".persist-area").each(function() {
    clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
    clonedHeaderRow
      .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
      .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
      .addClass("floatingHeader");

  });

  $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

Here is the full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Persistent Headers</title>

<style>

    body { 
     font: 14px Georgia, serif; 
    }

    p {
     margin: 0;
    }
   #page-wrap { 
    width: 500px; 
   /*
   height: 300px;
   background: red;
   overflow-y: auto;
    */
    margin: 100px auto; 
   }


  .some-other-area {
   margin: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
  }

  h2 {
   background: lightgrey;
   padding: 10px;
   font: 28px Georgia, Serif;
   margin:  0;
  }

 .floatingHeader {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
  }

 .persist-area {
 }



</style>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
   <script>
    function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "visible"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "visibility": "hidden"
           });      
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

   });
  </script>
  </head>

 <body>

 <div id="page-wrap">



  <section class="some-other-area persist-area">

    <h2 class="persist-header">Header 1</h2>

    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada   fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

   </section>

   <section class="some-other-area persist-area">

     <h2 class="persist-header">Header 2</h2>

     <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

   </section>

  <section class="some-other-area persist-area">

    <h2 class="persist-header">Header 3</h2>

    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  </section>

  <section class="some-other-area persist-area">

    <h2 class="persist-header">Header 4</h2>

    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  </section>

  <section class="some-other-area persist-area">

    <h2 class="persist-header">etc...</h2>

    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  </section>




    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

`

Comment: "pin" or "bind" the functionality to #page-wrap... what functionality?!

Comment: I were playing with your code, make de header fixed and instead of active one and desactive other, just keep the first header and only change the content.

Comment: is there a sample i can see? sorry, i'm a javascript noob.

Comment: @AdamJeffers, I'd like to "pin" or "bind" the sticky headers to the top of #page-wrap container instead the browser window.

Comment: Can you give us your HTML pls ;)

Comment: @AdamJeffers, I edited to post to have the full html ;)